# Showing the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$ is uniformly convergent in any bounded interval.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I want to show the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$

converges uniformly in any bounded interval and here is my justification.

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^2}{n^2}$ is uniformly convergent in any bounded interval. Let $M=\{|a|,|b|\}$, where $a,b$ are the endpoints of the interval and so we have
$$|\frac{(-1)^nx^2}{n^2}|\leq \frac{M^2}{n^2},$$ and so by M-Weierstrass test, we get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^2}{n^2}$  is uniformly convergent.

Secondly, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n},$$

which is uniformly convergent. Since both sums converge uniformly, we can say  teh series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}$$

converges.

However, the above series is not absolutely convergent, so I'm not sure if rewriting it as a combination of two uniformly convergent series is an accurate argument. I appreciate if you correct me.

Comment: I don't see a problem with what you've done. You've seen the same thing with the 2nd series ($\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$), which converges, doesn't converge absolutely, but converges uniformly on the whole of $\mathbb R$ because it simply doesn't depend on $x$.